# Download single file from FTP server in chunks in multiple threads using C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I just wanted to download a single file from FTP server in multiple segments in multiple threads using C#.

Is it possible to give ranges for the file download like in `HttpWebRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FtpWebRequest.ContentOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset) to specify the starting offset.

But [`FtpWebRequest.ContentLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentlength) is not implemented. To workaround that you have to abort the download, once you receive the desired amount of bytes.

```
const string name = "bigfile.dat";
const int chunks = 3;
const string url = "ftp://example.com/remote/path/" + name;
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

FtpWebRequest sizeRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
sizeRequest.Credentials = credentials;
sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
long size = sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;
Console.WriteLine($"File has {size} bytes");
long chunkLength = size / chunks;

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int chunk = 0; chunk < chunks; chunk++)
{
    int i = chunk;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = credentials;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.ContentOffset = chunkLength * i;
            long toread =
                (i < chunks - 1) ? chunkLength : size - request.ContentOffset;
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Downloading chunk {i + 1}/{chunks} with {toread} bytes ...");

            using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(name + "." + i))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                int read;
                while (((read = (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, toread)) > 0) &&
                       ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, read)) > 0))
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    toread -= read;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded chunk {i + 1}/{chunks}");
        }));
}

Console.WriteLine(
    "Started all chunks downloads, waiting for them to complete...");
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: thanks @Martin Prikryl. this seems to be working for me.:)

Answer (score 1):

First the disclaimer:
Multitasking is **not** a magical "go faster" bullet. If you apply it to the wrong problem, you end up with code that is more complex/prone to errors, more memory demanding and actually *slower* then the plain old singletasked/sequential approach. One alternate Task for a long running operation is genereally mandatory. But Massive parallelisation is only in very specific circumtances.

Generaly file operations are Disk or Network bound. Multitasking will not add any speedup to Disk or Network bound operations. And indeed might cause a slowdown, as [NCQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) and similar features have to straightern out your random access requests. That being said with Netowrking it *sometimes* can help. *Some* servers do apply a "per connection" limit, and thus splitting the download into multiple segments with their own connection can be a net speedup by.
But be certain this is actually the case here. Consider all but point 1 of the [Speed Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Asuming [FTPWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) is still the class you are using, it looks like [ContentLenght](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentlength) and [ContentOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset) might be the droids you are looking for. You basically use it similar to substring - each connection/sub-request takes X bytes from Y offset.

Comment: thanks for the information. yes actually our isp has per connection bandwidth limit. So in order to get the use of full bandwidth need to to divide into minimum no of segments.can you provide me sample piece of code which actually can download in segments from ftp server.

Comment: `FtpWebRequest.ContentLength` is not implemented. Even the link you have posted says that.

Comment: This isn't about multitasking. Parallel downloading is useful and a feature of all FTP clients, used to overcome rate limiting by the server or ISP. Microsoft download pages used to provide manual download links just for this reason

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I am confused. How would you implement working on multiple connections *without* Multitasking?

Comment: GetResponse().GetResponseStream() from ftpwebrequest for a very large size file does it load the complete file stream into memory?

Comment: @Vishnu: You mean `WebResponse.GetResponseStream` and it's HTTP brother? It depends entirely what you do with the `System.IO.Stream` Implementation you get. On it's own it should be a normal stream. Likely a "forward only"/"Firehose"/CanSeek = false stream - but still very much a stream. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream | The problem with streaming was never about the Streaming support of the Internet. But about teaching the *Representation* and *Application* layers about Streaming oddities.

Answer (score 0):

The default connection limit is 2. Use `ServicePoint` to change the limit.

```cs
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
ServicePoint sp = request.ServicePoint;
sp.ConnectionLimit = 4;
```